# AS3 Flash - Change an object's color on mouse move based off of mouse position

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an object whose color I need to change based off the mouse's x and y position while moving on it. How can I do this in code?

I can do it frame by frame and put different buttons, on mouse over for the button, we can go to other frame but this method is very tiring. Are there any easier methods?

What I'd like is to divide the image into to colored rows and columns and highlight the column and row the mouse is over.

Comment: Please share more details on how the color is supposed to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I'm interpreting the question:

> You need to change the color of an object based off the mouse's x & y position relative to that object

If that is the case, here is an example:

```
//listen for the mouse move event
object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler):

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent){

    //make a reference to the object that dispatched this event
    var object:DisplayObject = e.currentTarget as DisplayObject;

    //do your logic to determine the color based off the mouse position.


    //get the percentage of the mouse postion from 0 - 1
    var xPer:Number = e.localX / object.width;
    var yPer:Number = e.localY / object.height; 


    //One way you could do this, is change the Red/Green/Blue based of the mouse position like so:
    //create a color transformation object
    var colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1,1,1,1,0xFF * xPer,0xFF * xPer,0xFF * yPer,1);



    //OR, you could do it quadrant based like this:
    var color:uint = 0; //black default
    if(xPer >= .5 && yPer >= .5){
        //if the mouse is on the right bottom side of the object
        color = 0xFF0000; //make it red
    }
    if(xPer < .5 && yPer >=.5){
        //if the mosue is on the left bottom of the object
        color = 0x00FF00; //make it green
    }
    if(xPer >= .5 && yPer < .5){
        //if mouse is on the top right side
        color = 0x0000FF; //make it blue
    }
    if(xPer < .5 && yPer < .5){
        //if mouse is on the top left side
        color = 0xFF00FF; //make it purple
    }
    var colorTransformation = object.transform.colorTransform;
    colorTransform.color = color;




    //assign it to the object
    object.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Based off your comments, it sounds like you want something like this.

It assumes you have a MovieClip on the stage called `obj` with the bottom most child that is the Bitmap you want to work with.

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

//get a reference to the actual bitmap
//this assumes the bitmap is the bottom most child of the MovieClip container called obj
var bitmap:Bitmap = Bitmap(obj.getChildAt(0));
var bitmapData:BitmapData = bitmap.bitmapData;

//store the original pixel data
var originalPixels:ByteArray = bitmapData.getPixels(bitmap.getBounds(bitmap));


var rows:int = 3;
var rowHeight:Number = Math.ceil(bitmap.height / rows);
var curRow:int = -1;

var cols:int = 3;
var colWidth:int = Math.ceil(bitmap.width / cols);
var curCol:int = -1;

//listen for the mouse move event
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, restoreBitmap);

function restoreBitmap(e:Event = null):void {
    //restore original
    if(e){
        //if this function was triggered from the mouse event
        curRow = -1;
        curCol = -1;
    }
    originalPixels.position = 0;
    bitmapData.setPixels(bitmap.getBounds(bitmap),originalPixels);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent){
    //figure out what row the mouse is in and make the row rectangle
    var row:int = Math.floor(bitmap.y + e.localY / rowHeight);
    var col:int = Math.floor(bitmap.x + e.localX / colWidth);

    var rect:Rectangle;

    //if either the row or column has changed, restore the pixels to original and draw new ones
    if(row != curRow || col != curCol){
        restoreBitmap();

        curCol = col;
        rect = new Rectangle(curCol * colWidth, 0, colWidth, bitmap.height);

        colorRect(bitmapData, rect,0x0000FF);

        curRow = row;
        rect = new Rectangle(0, row * rowHeight, bitmap.width, rowHeight);

        colorRect(bitmapData, rect,0x00FF00);
    }
}

function colorRect(bmd:BitmapData, rect:Rectangle, color:uint) {
    var row:int = 0;
    var col:int = 0;

    while(row * col <= rect.width * rect.height){
        bmd.setPixel(int(rect.x) + col, int(rect.y) + row, color);

        //incriment the row/column
        if (col < rect.width -1) {
            col++;
        }else {
            row++
            col = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, is FlashPro will make a Bitmap dragged onto the timeline a `Shape` unless you go to the bitmap's properties and tell it to **export for actionscript**.

Also, the bitmap can not be scaled.  Do any scaling to the container/MovieClip that holds the bitmap.

---

Here is same result, but done with masks, you'll likely see how much faster this method is:

```
//get a reference to the actual bitmap
//this assumes the bitmap is the bottom most child of the MovieClip container called obj
var bitmap:Bitmap = Bitmap(obj.getChildAt(0));
var bitmapData:BitmapData = bitmap.bitmapData;

//clone it twice and add the clones to container (obj)
//also add mask objects
var cloneCol:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
var cloneColMask:Shape = new Shape();
cloneCol.mask = cloneColMask;
obj.addChild(cloneCol);
obj.addChild(cloneColMask);

//tint the clones
var ct:ColorTransform = cloneCol.transform.colorTransform;
ct.color = 0x00FF00;
cloneCol.transform.colorTransform = ct;


var cloneRow:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
var cloneRowMask:Shape = new Shape();
cloneRow.mask = cloneRowMask;
obj.addChild(cloneRow);
obj.addChild(cloneRowMask);

ct.color = 0x0000FF;
cloneRow.transform.colorTransform = ct;


//setup your columns and rows

var rows:int = 3;
var rowHeight:Number = Math.ceil(bitmap.height / rows);
var curRow:int = -1;

var cols:int = 3;
var colWidth:int = Math.ceil(bitmap.width / cols);
var curCol:int = -1;

//listen for the mouse move event
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, restoreBitmap);

function restoreBitmap(e:Event = null):void {
    cloneRowMask.graphics.clear();
    cloneColMask.graphics.clear();
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent){
    //figure out what row the mouse is in and make the row rectangle
    var row:int = Math.floor(bitmap.y + e.localY / rowHeight);
    var col:int = Math.floor(bitmap.x + e.localX / colWidth);

    var rect:Rectangle;

    if(row != curRow || col != curCol){
        curCol = col;
        cloneColMask.graphics.clear();
        cloneColMask.graphics.beginFill(0);
        cloneColMask.graphics.drawRect(curCol * colWidth, 0, colWidth, bitmap.height);

        curRow = row;
        cloneRowMask.graphics.clear();
        cloneRowMask.graphics.beginFill(0);
        cloneRowMask.graphics.drawRect(0, row * rowHeight, bitmap.width, rowHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your interpretion is right, while can you explain your code please? will it work like this or it needs other work? have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried it, but I have no idea how you want to determine the color

Comment: I tried it but I am getting this error Scene in the last line 1119: Access of possibly undefined property transfrom through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: typo, change `transfrom` to `transform`  and `colorTransformation` to `colorTransform`.  I updated the answer to fix the typos

Comment: it is working without errors but it changes the whole object color, what i need is to change only the parts mouse over on it (not the whole object), I need the object to be changed while the mouse is going over it and as we are moving on the object, the current x and y changes

Comment: You only want to change one pixel under the mouse?  I don't understand I think. Can do a mock up screenshot maybe?

Comment: If I am having an image like this http://st-takla.org/Gallery/var/albums/Words/Numbers/www-St-Takla-org--Number-2-Two.gif?m=1419425407 , I need to change the color of the row or column of this object when mouse is moving on it and the color continues to be changed while I am moving on the object itself

Comment: Can you make a mock up of what it should look like with the mouse over it?  So you want it similar to the quadrant based example I've made, however you only want that quadrant to change color?  (and the quadrants are rows and columns)

Comment: yes the quadrant are rows and columns, for example if the mouse is over point x=10, y=70, and this point is into the object then the row or column color will be change and so on

Comment: Well, that get's much more complicated, as you'll have to duplicate the image, then mask the duplicate so only that quadrant is visible.

Comment: Can you direct me to an example for doing this mask on mouse over? while I think it is close now, why couldn't we change object pixel itself?

Comment: I've shown a pixel manipulation example. It works, but is fairly slow when working with larger bitmaps - as is the nature of pixel manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much 
Also I did other solution. I divided the image into different small parts and did every part a button then I changed every button color while mouse is over on it